# How to extend WooCommerce API to show bookable product availability rules?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I've made a custom plugin with a custom API end point.

I would like to access my bookable products availability times so I can use the API with a react front end.

So far I have this function that my custom endpoint is attached to:

```
function get_data() {

               $args = array( 'limit' => 1, 'type' => 'booking',  );

               $products = wc_get_products( $args );


               return $products;
           }
```

When I call my end point in Postman all I get is this:

[image]

Why is the array for `availability_rules` empty and why are there no other details about my bookable product being returned by the WooCommerce `wc_get_product()` function?

Comment: I believe that the `wc_get_products` function just returns default `WC_Product` objects, disregarding any custom data. Where are the `availability_rules` stored? In post meta?

Comment: Yeah and thats what I would like, I would like the default WC_Product objects but it returns empty. `availability_rules` is returned when I specify the type as booking. So surely its a default object too?